# Vmware Fusion + Ubuntu 12.04, shortcut

Tags: keyboard, vmware, unix

I'm running vmware fusion 5 under OS X Mountain Lion. My virtual machine is running Ubuntu 12.04.

I have two fastidious shortcuts which I would like to disable:

- When I press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>, Ubuntu opens the dash and shows under the text field a set of icons.

[image: Command shortcut effect]

- When I press the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> keys (which I use for making accented letters) Ubuntu opens the dash without showing the icons under the text field.

[image: Option+` shortcut effect]

How can I disable or block these shortcuts?

Comment: This seems more a question about configuring Ubuntu, or am I mistaking? If so maybe you should ask it on askubuntu.com instead?

Comment: @Gerry I think its valid for both, becuase there some special associations between the keys of a Mac keyboard with the keys of a virtual machine. Btw I would post the same question also there. Is it ok?

Comment: I don't see how the answer to this question would be any different for Ubuntu virtualized under Windows or under Ubuntu itself for example, so imo it's probably off-topic here.

Comment: I don't agree with you because as I said, vmware decide how the real keys are mapped to the virtualized keeys. So, since the mac have a different keyboard, the case is different from a case in which Ubuntu is virtualized for example on a windows pc. However I posted it on askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1):

I tried playing around with the keyboard settings in Fusion, in particular editing particular profiles.

This did not change the behaviour of <kbd>⌘</kbd> in unity. I did not play around with <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> as I could not replicate your Ubuntu behaviour.

The only way I found to disable the <kbd>⌘</kbd> shortcut is to install `gconf-editor` and remove the shortcut from within Ubuntu running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay --type bool false
```